# Time complexity Theory

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

If f(n) is O(g(n)) and f(n) is O(h(n)) then what is the relation between f(n), g(n) and h(n) ?

I saw this question in many places and never able to figure out the difference. For me it appeared as g(n) and h(n) as same whereas that is not the case.

I am giving out the possible options that could be possible, please tell which condition is fulfilled:

A. f(n) + g(n) is O(h(n))

B. g(n) + h(n) is O(f(n))

C. f(n) is O(g(n) + h(n))

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CS, not practical programming. Try cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Barmar Don't you have an idea why one cannot use that forum in "doesn't belong here" flag?

Comment: I think 3rd option is the closest, please tell if I am wrong

Comment: Without confirming or denying, I would ask "Why do you think C is correct?"

Comment: @chepner Because other two option doesn't make any sense. The only achievable solution appears to be the third one

Comment: Your teacher (I assume this is a homework problem) might want a more rigorous explanation. Suppose I defined `z` such that for all `n`, `z(n) = f(n) + g(n)`. Would you immediately reject the possibility that `z(n) = O(h(n))`?

Comment: @chepner This question I saw earlier also and most recently it was asked in a microsoft exam. And yeah possibility for the first option also remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just come back to the definition of the "Big-Oh" notation. Here, f(n) is O(h(n)) which mean that there is an integer n<sub>h</sub> and real constants c<sub>h,1</sub> and c<sub>h,2</sub> such that for every n > n<sub>h</sub>,

> c<sub>h,1</sub>. h(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ c<sub>h,2</sub>. h(n)    (1)

Similarly since f is also O(g(n)), there is also n<sub>g</sub> and real constants c<sub>g,1</sub> and c<sub>g,2</sub> such that for every n > n<sub>g</sub>

> c<sub>g,1</sub>. g(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ c<sub>g,2</sub>. g(n)    (2)

From there, if you take n > max(n<sub>h</sub>, n<sub>g</sub>), both inequalities hold, but they don't bring you any knowledge about the relationship between h and g.

**EDIT :**

Since you cannot say anything between h and g, you cannot prove assumptions A and B without further knowledge. On the other hand, for any n > max(n<sub>h</sub>, n<sub>g</sub>), you have [ 1/2 . (1) + 1/2 . (2) ] :

> 1/2 . c<sub>g,1</sub>. g(n) + 1/2 c<sub>h,1</sub>. h(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ 1/2 . c<sub>g,2</sub>. g(n) + 1/2 . c<sub>h,2</sub>. h(n)

And then

> 1/2 . min(c<sub>g,1</sub>, c<sub>h,1</sub>).(g(n) + h(n)) ≤ f(n) ≤ 1/2.max(c<sub>g,1</sub>, c<sub>h,1</sub>).(g(n) + h(n))
>   Hence, f(n) is O(g(n) + h(n))

Comment: isn't the first option possibility there.As said by chepner in the comments : Suppose I defined z such that for all n, z(n) = f(n) + g(n). Would you immediately reject the possibility that z(n) = O(h(n))?

Comment: @user4058730, no because you cannot bound g(n) by h(n) with such little knowledge. I don't say it's definitely false, I just say you cannot prove it is always true under the given hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

We have:

- f(n) is O(g(n)) (given)
- f(n) is O(h(n)) (given)

You can't say anything about the relationship between g(n) and h(n) as one may be "bigger" than the other or vice versa. All you know is that f(n) is bounded by g(n) and that f(n) is bounded by h(n) but that doesn't say anything on how g(n) and h(n) relate to each other.

Comment: The relation between these equations, functions are they are in the same complexity class. no?

Comment: You cant really claim which is bigger or smaller, question is about the complexity class of them. Hence they are in the same complexity class.

Comment: Given that `f = O(g)` and `f = O(h)`, you can't say anything about how `g` and `h` are related. Either `g = O(h)` or `h = O(g)`, but you don't know which without further information.

Comment: I think 3rd option is the closest, please tell if I am wrong

Comment: @chepner `g` and `h` could be completely unrelated, asymptotically. Take `f(n) = n`, `g(n) = n² + sin n` and `h(n) = n² + cos n`. Not everything is polynomials and polylogs.

Comment: Yeah, I realized there was probably a pair of functions involving sin/cos that would prevent g and h from bounding each other. That doesn't detract from the main point though that you can't determine which of the (now three) possibilities for g and h is true.